# Subscribing to Presence Changes in Skype for Buisness Client

Tags: skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk

I want to subscribe to my own presence changes in my Skype for Buisness Client and tried the `ContactInformationChanged` event from the Lync Client SDK. The documentation on subscribing to presence ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/desktop/how-to-subscribe-to-enhanced-presence-content)) writes that their is also a need to create a Subscription, fill it with the ContactInformationTypes i want to subscribe to, add the contact i want to subscribe to and call `Subscribe()` on the subscription object. Now unless i misunderstood the documentation you still habe to subscribe to the `ContactInformationChanged` event if you do that. The thing is even if i leave out the subscription creation part and just subscribe to the `ContactInformationChanged` event it makes no difference. For example if i do this:

```
        var selfContact = m_lyncClient.Self.Contact;
        selfContact.ContactInformationChanged += Contact_ContactInformationChanged;

        m_subscription = m_lyncClient.ContactManager.CreateSubscription();
        m_subscription.AddContact(selfContact);
        List<ContactInformationType> contactInformationList = new List<ContactInformationType>
        {
            ContactInformationType.Activity,
            ContactInformationType.Availability,
            ContactInformationType.ActivityId,
            ContactInformationType.CustomActivity,
        };
        m_subscription.Subscribe(ContactSubscriptionRefreshRate.High, contactInformationList);
```

I get event messages for `ContactInformationChanged` with a `ContactInformationType`that i didn't specify.

My Questions:

- Is the Subscription creation part even necessary?
- Is there a way to just get Presence Notifications of specific `ContactInformationType`'s changing (like Availabilty for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the Subscription creation part even necessary?

For your own contact, no you don't need to create a subscription.

> Is there a way to just get Presence Notifications of specific ContactInformationType's changing (like Availabilty for example)?

No.  You just need to filter out all other callbacks like so:

```
private void Contact_ContactInformationChanged(object sender, ContactInformationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedContactInformation.Contains(ContactInformationType.Availability) ||
        e.ChangedContactInformation.Contains(ContactInformationType.ActivityId) ||
        e.ChangedContactInformation.Contains(ContactInformationType.CustomActivity))
    {
        OnLyncPresenceChanged();
    }
}
```